# Insertion in MySQL takes a lot of time

Tags: mysql

I have a lot of tables and few tables have around 20 million records.
Now I do some calculations on these tables before showing the result to the UI.

For that I have created stored procedure.
In the stored procedure I am using temprorary tables to store select query records, do join, do processing and then return result.

I have written query like this

```
Insert INTO A
SELECT * from B JOIN c ....
```

Now my select query here does not take time (I have optimize it using explain extended) but my Insert into takes a lot of time since the output of select is in million. My table A is temprorary.

And Also I have do some processing on this A table after that.

My query is is there a way where I can skip inserting this insert.
I can take the result in a seperate table variable(if any) and then do processing instead of inserting all that in temprorary and then again doing some processing  on it.

Adding my stored procedure here

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS 6_4_1n2_PortUtil_temp;
DELIMITER |

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 6_4_1n2_PortUtil_temp(utilType VARCHAR(100),service varchar(5000),p_networkType VARCHAR(20),inputCity varchar(5000),inputNodeName varchar(5000), startTime timestamp,endTime timestamp)
BEGIN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_SERVICE_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEIF_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEIF_TBL_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEName_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_ROUTERTRAFFIC_VLANPRT_SCALE1_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TRAFFIC_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS FINAL_FETCH;

SELECT now();

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_SERVICE_TBL(nodeName varchar(256),NodeNumber int) ENGINE INNODB;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_NODEName_TBL(nodeName varchar(256),NodeNumber int) ENGINE INNODB;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_NODEIF_TBL(NodeNumber int,IfIndex INTEGER,IfSpeed FLOAT,IfDescr VARCHAR(100),IfAlias VARCHAR(100)) ENGINE INNODB;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_NODEIF_TBL_1(NodeNumber int,IfIndex INTEGER,IfSpeed FLOAT,IfDescr VARCHAR(100),IfAlias VARCHAR(100)) ENGINE INNODB;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL(NodeName Varchar(256),NodeNumber int,IfIndex INTEGER,IfSpeed FLOAT,IfDescr VARCHAR(100),IfAlias VARCHAR(100),PortID BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0) ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TRAFFIC_TBL(
    PortID                  BIGINT(20),
    NodeName        VARCHAR(100),
    IfDescr         VARCHAR(100),
    IfSpeed         VARCHAR(100),
    InErrPkts       BIGINT(20),
    RcvOctets       BIGINT(20),
    TxOctets        BIGINT(20),
    Time_1          TIMESTAMP) ENGINE INNODB;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL(
        PortID          BIGINT(20), 
    maxTrafficValueIn   BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0,
    maxOutTrafficValueOut   BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0,
    avgTrafficValueIn   BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0,
    avgTrafficValueOut  BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0,
    CRCError        BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0,
    UpTime          INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    Reliablity      INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    AvgUtilIn       float DEFAULT 0,
    AvgUtilOut      float DEFAULT 0,
    PeakUtilIn      float DEFAULT 0, 
    PeakUtilOut         float DEFAULT 0,
    ThresholdExceed     INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    inPeakTime      timestamp DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    outPeakTime         timestamp DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00') ENGINE INNODB;

SET @where = '';
IF service='ALL'
THEN

    SET @where = '';
ELSE
set @a=1;
set @like="";
select REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(service, ',', @a),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(service, ',', @a -1)) + 1),',','') into @service;
while(@service != "")
DO
    IF(@like = "")
    THEN
        SET @like = CONCAT("NodeName like '%",SUBSTRING(@service,2,3),"%'");
    ELSE
        SET @like = CONCAT(@like," or NodeName like '%",SUBSTRING(@service,2,3),"%'");
    END IF;
    set @a=@a+1;
    select REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(service, ',', @a),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(service, ',', @a -1)) + 1),',','') into @service;
END WHILE;
SET @where = CONCAT(" where",@like);
END IF;


Set @where2 = '';
IF inputCity='ALL'
THEN
        set @where2 = '';
ELSE
    set @where2 = CONCAT(' and substring(NodeName,1,3) in (',inputCity,')'); 
END IF;


SET @where3 = '';
IF inputNodeName='ALL'
THEN
       set @where3 = '';
ELSE
    set @where3 = CONCAT(' and NodeName in (',inputNodeName,')');   
END IF;

SET @query1 := CONCAT("INSERT INTO TEMP_NODEName_TBL SELECT distinct NodeName,NodeNumber from NODE_TBL",@where, @where2, @where3);

SELECT @query1;

PREPARE statement1 from @query1;
EXECUTE statement1;
DEALLOCATE Prepare statement1;

CREATE INDEX n1 ON TEMP_NODEName_TBL(NodeNumber);
CREATE INDEX i1 ON TEMP_NODEIF_TBL(NodeNumber,IfIndex);
CREATE INDEX portIDIndex1 on TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL(PortID);

SET @where4 = '';
IF (utilType='ALL')
THEN
    SET @where = '';
ELSE 
    If (utilType = "'AESI-IN'")
    THEN
        SET @where4 = " where IfAlias like '%AESI-IN%'";
    ELSE 
        SET @where4 = " where IfAlias NOT like '%AESI-IN%'";
    END IF;
END IF;




CREATE INDEX i2 ON TEMP_NODEIF_TBL_1(NodeNumber,IfIndex);
CREATE INDEX i3 ON TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL(NodeNumber,IfIndex);

SET @where5 = ''; 
IF(p_networkType != 'ALL')
THEN
set @r1= SUBSTRING(p_networkType,2,3);
set @r2= SUBSTRING(p_networkType,8,3);
set @r3= SUBSTRING(p_networkType,14,3);
    SET @where5 = CONCAT(" and IfAlias like '%",@r1,"%'");

    if(@r2 != "")
    THEN
        SET @where5 = CONCAT(" and IfAlias like '%",@r2,"%'");

        IF(@r3 != "")
        THEN
            SET @where5 = CONCAT(" and IfAlias like '%",@r3,"%'");
        END IF;
    END IF;
END IF;

SET @query2 := CONCAT("INSERT INTO TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL(NodeName,NodeNumber,IfIndex,IfSpeed,IfDescr,IfAlias)  SELECT distinct b.NodeName, a.NodeNumber, a.IfIndex,a.IfSpeed,a.IfDescr,a.IfAlias from NODEIF_TBL a JOIN TEMP_NODEName_TBL b ON a.NodeNumber = b.NodeNumber ", @where4, @where5);

SELECT @query2; 
PREPARE statement1 from @query2;
EXECUTE statement1;
DEALLOCATE Prepare statement1;

SELECT "DROP TEMPORARY TABLES";

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEIF_TBL;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEIF_TBL_1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_NODEName_TBL;

update TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL a,VLANPRT_TBL b  set a.PortID = PrtID  where a.NodeNumber = b.NodeID and a.IfIndex = b.IfIndex;

SELECT "Update Temporary tables";

delete from TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL where PortID = 0;

SELECT now();

INSERT INTO TRAFFIC_TBL 
            SELECT a.PortID,NodeName,IfDescr,IfSpeed,InErrPkts,RcvOctets,TxOctets,Time_1 FROM ROUTERTRAFFIC_VLANPRT_SCALE1_TBL a JOIN TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL b ON a.PortID = b.PortID  where Time_1>startTime and Time_1<endTime;

SELECT now();

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS EXCEED_COUNT;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE EXCEED_COUNT (PortID BIGINT(20), Exceed INTEGER);

INSERT INTO EXCEED_COUNT
        select PortID,count(RcvOctets) from TRAFFIC_TBL where (RcvOctets/(IfSpeed*10)>70 or TxOctets/(IfSpeed*10)>70) group by PortID;

INSERT INTO TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL (PortID, maxTrafficValueIn,maxOutTrafficValueOut,avgTrafficValueIn,avgTrafficValueOut,CRCError,AvgUtilIn,AvgUtilOut,PeakUtilIn,PeakUtilOut)
    SELECT  PortID,max(RcvOctets),max(TxOctets),avg(RcvOctets),avg(TxOctets), sum(InErrPkts),
    IF((IfSpeed=0),"0",(avg(RcvOctets)/(IfSpeed*10))),
    IF((IfSpeed=0),"0",(avg(TxOctets)/(IfSpeed*10))),
    IF((IfSpeed=0),"0",(max(RcvOctets)/(IfSpeed*10))),
    IF((IfSpeed=0),"0",(max(TxOctets)/(IfSpeed*10)))
        from TRAFFIC_TBL group by PortID;

CREATE INDEX portIDIndex2 on TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL(PortID);
CREATE INDEX portIDIndex3 on EXCEED_COUNT(PortID);

UPDATE TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL A JOIN TRAFFIC_TBL B ON A.PortId=B.PortId SET inPeakTime=B.Time_1 where B.RcvOctets=A.maxTrafficValueIn;
UPDATE TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL A JOIN TRAFFIC_TBL B ON A.PortId=B.PortId SET outPeakTime=B.Time_1 where B.TxOctets=A.maxOutTrafficValueOut;

UPDATE TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL A JOIN EXCEED_COUNT B ON (A.PortID = B.PortID)
    set ThresholdExceed = Exceed;

SELECT substring(NodeName,5,3) as ServiceType,
CASE
WHEN IfAlias like '%SWH%' THEN "Trunk"
WHEN IfAlias like '%AES%' THEN "Backbone"
WHEN IfAlias like '%RTR%' THEN "Back-to-Back"
ELSE "-"
END ,
NodeName,IfDescr,ROUND(maxTrafficValueIn/1000,2),ROUND(maxOutTrafficValueOut/1000,2),ROUND(avgTrafficValueIn/1000,2),ROUND(avgTrafficValueOut/1000,2),ROUND(CRCError/1000,2),0,0,ROUND(AvgUtilIn,2),ROUND(AvgUtilOut,2),ROUND(PeakUtilIn,2),ROUND(PeakUtilOut,2),ThresholdExceed,inPeakTime,outPeakTime  from TEMP_TRAFFIC_TBL a ,TEMP_NODEANDIF_TBL b where a.PortID = b.PortID ;

SELECT now(); 

END |
DELIMITER ;
```

My ROUTERTRAFFIC_VLANPRT_SCALE1_TBL contains around 20 million records and NodeIF_TBL around 1 lakhs records. My VLANPRT_TBL also contains around 1 lakh records.
Also I have BTree indexing set on time_1 so that the join on the big table do not take time

Comment: please show `schema` and `query`, we can not help without it!!

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Why do you want 20 million records into a temporary table?

Comment: How you measure `a lot of time`?

Comment: I have a table B with around 2 million records. and another table with C with 1 lakhs records. I join these tables and with where clause I get a count of 2 lakhs records using the select. Now I write this to a temprorary table to do further processing on that table. Now the select statement is taking around 1 sec and the insert is taking around 10 sec which I do not want. I want to reduce this insertion time

Comment: Breaking it down into a transactions of a few hundred inserts may speed things up. But the exact number of inserts which yields the best speed needs to be tested.

Comment: Is there a  way wherein I can avoid this insert and use the output of Select query into some other query within the same stored procedure without copying the data into temporary tables?

Comment: As @NoobEditor asked you -- we need you to show us what exactly you are doing otherwise we're just guessing based on the limited information you did give us.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in your stored procedure... how can I give you an alternative to what you are already doing if you don't even tell me **what** you are already doing?

Comment: Can I send you my stored procedure. I may not be able to explain when I am doing in the comments section.

Comment: My  max_heap_table_size  16777216. This means I have only 16 mb of heap reserved. Is it because of this I am not getting the advantage to temporary tables?

Comment: @Nipun you can edit your initial question to add the stored procedure there.

Comment: The max_heap_table_size might be the limit I was talking about -- I'm not sure. A word of caution: don't go around changing settings without reading about the possible implications, you may not like the results. Also try to exhaust logical / software improvements to your situation before deciding to "throw more hardware at the problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Temporary tables:

Temporary tables start out in the memory and if the surpass a certain limitation they will be written to disk. If the select yields millions and you're writing those millions to disk then that's your problem.

Needing a temporary table with millions of records is usually a sign of doing something wrong. Perhaps you should further filter the data before inserting it into the temporary table for processing.

### Disk I/O thrashing:

We have a few `INSERT` cases:

1. `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`
2. `INSERT INGORE INTO ... SELECT`
3. `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`

For 1. each insert has its own transaction and writes to disk individually meaning lots of tiny I/O operations.

For 2. the same applies except the data is also being read from the disk (slightly more I/O operations).

For 3. the whole operation is one big transaction meaning one big disk I/O at the very end (the commit) of the transaction. More often it happens that the information contained in the big transaction cannot be held entirely in memory so it is written to disk temporarily before the final commit and then copied from there into the designated area where it should reside.

In all 3 cases disk I/O thrashing occurs, to prevent this you would group small operations into average sized operations, and break huge operations into average sized operations.

For 1. you need to wrap every N inserts in a transaction.

For 2. and 3. you need to `LIMIT` the `SELECT` clause to N and repeat the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with an added `OFFSET` of N until you finish all records.

Either should be fairly easy to do if you're using a scripting language to run your queries.

Comment: Why you think that inserting into table by `INSERT INTO SELECT`  writes to disk row by row?

Comment: Because each insert is guaranteed to be an "atomic" operation -- a transaction on its own -- which commits its data to disk at the end.

Comment: Really? Do you think that in `INSERT INTO SELECT` you have bunch of implicit transactions of inserted row count?

Comment: When you `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` 100 rows and the 50th has a duplicate primary key, the 50 `INSERT`s already performed are not rolled back, they're just left there -- only the current `INSERT` is rolled back and the rest of them are not performed due to the error.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm testing it now -- I'll be back to confirm.

Comment: Either way if an `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` is *one big transaction* that is equally bad in terms of disk I/O thrashing because it writes the data twice -- once it's written in a separate container (uncommitted) because it doesn't fit into memory and the second time it's committed -- batching would help either way.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan you're write -- the entire `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is one big transaction (unless you use `INSERT IGNORE` -- which is what I was thinking about). I'm updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I am here inserting into a temporary table and temporary tables are stored in memory. Should this Insert into operation faster?

Comment: @Nipun The first phrase in my answer says clearly: temporary tables are held in memory **only if they are small enough**, if not then they are stored to disk.

Comment: @Nipun you simply can't have millions of records in memory if they don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

Its not needed to store in a temporary table the output from a query in order to use it in another query. You can make this:

```
Select t1.* from (select * from A where condition1)as t1  where condition2
```

Here is an example of a query i had to do.

```
select avg(v1) as v1avg ,start_date_time as time, timekey as time_key from (select ATable.*, ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_date_time)/(60*60)) as timekey  from ATable where start_date_time between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2014-01-10 00:00:00')as t1 group by timekey;
```

Comment: I have heard that sub queries are slower. Is it true?

Comment: No. Subqueries "can" be slower if the query-optimizer can't optimize them.

Comment: There are 3 types of subqueries: subqueries in the `SELECT` area (they need to be run once for every row in the result); subqueries in the `FROM` (or `JOIN`) area need to be run once to build the result-table; subqueries in the `WHERE` area which need to be run once to build the result-table.

Comment: @Nipun think about these 3 types of subqueries and imagine which one is slow and which one is not; think which can be optimized and which can't etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot Mihai. One last query.
When we do a select * in stored procedure how does internally it works. Does mysql creates a temporary table and then shows the rows of that temporary tables on the console or there is some other behavior.
And if it creates a temporary table internally can I use that table instead of creating my own temporary table and inserting elements in it

Comment: @Nipun -- it creates a "result set" which can be iterated with a cursor using the `CREATE CURSOR ... FOR SELECT ...` but the `CURSOR` syntax and capabilities have their own limits too. I'd try this approach if I were in your place but I really can't tell you anything about performance.